# Angular 4, Как получить данные из файла index.html

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

В программу нужно передавать некоторый параметр, но передача должна осуществляться из файла index.html, то есть из файла на котором располагается селектор app-root. Если создать index.html и index2.html, то нужно из каждого файла иметь возможность передавать разные значения некоторого параметра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EsccNgapp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root apptype="standart"></app-root>
</body>
```

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  apptype: string;
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.apptype = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('apptype');
  }
}
```